# can Valgrind detect invalid read on stack variable

Tags: valgrind

I have written a small code to verify Valgrind is able to detect some invalid read, it looks like it did not detect it. can this be done?

```
int a[2];
printf("test %d", a[100]);
```

if exchanging the array to be dynamically allocated then the Valgrind works fine. (invalid read of size 4)

Answer (score 0):

valgrind --tool=memcheck (the default tool) does not detect such problems.

There is an experimental tool  valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck
that has as objective to detects such bugs, but it never worked
properly, and the tool will likely be removed from valgrind distribution.

To my knowledge, gcc/clang sanitizer is the technique to use to detect such bugs.